# How to select multiple properties properly?

Tags: c#, select, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

`MyObject` have two property named `p1` and `p2` in `int` type ;now I want for each of `MyObject` take `p1` and `p2` and add those up. I tried this:

```
int p1Sum = 0, p2Sum = 0;
foreach (int[] ps in new MyEntity().MyObject.Select(o => new { o.p1, o.p2 }))
       {
            p1Sum += ps[0];
            p2Sum += ps[1];   
       }
```

but says:

> cannot convert `AnonymousType#1` to `int[]`

on `foreach`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I really don't know which answer should I accept! all answers are perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var ps in new MyEntity().MyObject.Select(o => new { o.p1, o.p2 }))
       {
            p1Sum += ps.p1;
            p2Sum += ps.p2;   
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

jyparask's answer will definitely work, but it's worth considering using `Sum` twice instead - it will involve two database calls, but it may (check!) avoid fetching all the individual values locally:

```
var entities = new MyEntity().MyObject;
var p1Sum = entities.Sum(x => x.p1);
var p2Sum = entities.Sum(x => x.p2);
```

Now there's at least *logically* the possibility of inconsistency here - some entities may be removed or added between the two `Sum` calls. However, it's possible that EF will ensure that doesn't happen (e.g. via caching) or it may not be relevant in your situation. It's definitely something you should think consider.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jon Skeet and jyparask answer you can also try :

```
var result = (new MyEntity().MyObject
             .GroupBy(_=> 0)
             .Select(r=> new 
                   {
                    p1Sum = r.Sum(x=> x.p1)
                    p2Sum = r.Sum(x=> x.p2)
                   })
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above would result in a single query fetching only `Sum` for both columns, You may look at the query generated and its execution plan if you are concerned about the performance.

```
if(result != null) 
  {
   Console.WriteLine("p1Sum = " + result.p1Sum);
   Console.WriteLine("p2Sum = " + result.p2Sum);
  }
```

Comment: why `.GroupBy(_=> 0)` needed?

Comment: @majidgeek, Here GroupBy is not really needed, but to get two different sums in one query it is used. EF might optimize this query and git rid of group by in SQL but that's how it would be required to work in LINQ. 
In current `.GroupBy(_=>0)` means that the lambda is receiving a paramater which is not used and effectively grouping by 0.